# How to rewrite variable URL with htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite URLs as `domain.com/page` using **.htaccess** where **page** is a variable.

I am using the following code for it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?room_name=$1 [L]
```

But it isn't working as desired. I think it is making all URLs like `domain.com/login` or `domain.com/register` act as the variable `page`.

How do I rewrite the URL such that the variable `page` rewrites only for `index.php`?

**Edit:** If `domain.com/page` is not possible, `domain.com/room/page` is also acceptable.

**Edit 2:**
I have been using the following URL rewrites for this purpose earlier:

```
RewriteRule ^teen index.php?room_name=teen [L]
RewriteRule ^singles index.php?room_name=singles [L]
```

But as these pages are supposed to be user generated it is not possible to write for every page. I just want to automate these URL rewrites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If `domain.com/page` is not possible, `domain.com/room/page` is also acceptable

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^room/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?room_name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Also if you're using relative URLs for css/js/images then add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: I have done it but it's not working. Do the PHP `include` also need to be relative?

Comment: Check the URL: https://chatadda.com/singles & login using guest & then check the URL - https://chatadda.com/room/singles you will get the issue.

Comment: click on Login as guest

Comment: check chatadda.com/room/singles even after adding `base` and fixing all the JS errors, it's still not working

Comment: Did you check source code in browser? There is still no `base` tag

Comment: Yes. Now it's fixed. Thank you very much for your help. I have accepted your answer and upvoted it. Do you mind upvoting this question as someone didn't understand the question and downvoted it which will bar me from posting questions henceforth.